# Delete rows in temp table that contain names from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row, temp-tables

I'm populating a temp table with a list of SQL Agent Jobs that require enabling. This part is easy enough.

Before I run through this list of jobs in the temp table to enable them all I want to delete any rows in this temp table based on a list of job names in another table.

**Example of Temp Table.**

```
3 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='GetPendingFSJobCount', @enabled=1 
4 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='ResetFailedOneTimeJobs - CMAdmin',@enabled=1 
5 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='DR_Backup', @enabled=1
```

**Example of other Table.**

```
1 DR_Backup
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide examples of your temp table and the other table that you are using? It seems like you should just be able to join your temp table to your other table to delete the values you want.

Comment: Can you show tables structures and some data?

Comment: Example of Temp Table.3 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='GetPendingFSJobCount', @enabled=1 4 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='ResetFailedOneTimeJobs - CMAdmin', @enabled=1 5 USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='DBDimensionMaintenance - TReMBI', @enabled=1

Comment: Example of other table1 DR_Backup
NULL NULL

Comment: When we ask for examples, it's almost always a better idea to *edit* your question to add the information - you can also highlight blocks of code and hit the `{}` button, which gives us syntax highlighting - as you may have noticed, code in comments isn't very readable.

Comment: I've believe I've formated the original question as per suggestion.  Thank you in advance.